# Force Outlook to Send Mail on or after a Specific Time

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

Need VBA code to send Outlook e-mail at 2.30pm, if after 2.30pm send straight away?

it would need to precede

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show
```

Comment: like `if now > 14.30`? Now has a date though, so you'd need to extract only the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the rest of your code or what you're trying to do, this should answer your specific question -

```
Sub test()
If Hour(Now) >= 14 And Minute(Now) >= 30 Then
'do stuff
  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, worked like a treat

Comment: Excellent. If this solved your problem, please click the green check-mark next to the answer to mark the question as solved.